# Typescript complains when mapping numeric enum to string enum

Tags: typescript, enums, grpc, typescript-typings

I'm trying to map a number-based enum generated from a gRPC proto file into a string-based enum for use in my REST API.

The mapping works but TS complain, giving this error.

What have I done wrong, and how to fix?

```
types/mapping.ts:5:14 - error TS2739: Type '{ 3: OperationMode.LEARNING; 2: OperationMode.MAINTENANCE; 1: OperationMode.NORMAL; 4: OperationMode.TESTING; 0: undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ 0: OperationMode | undefined; OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED: OperationMode | undefined; OPERATION_NORMAL: OperationMode | undefined; ... 6 more ...; 4: OperationMode | undefined; }': OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED, OPERATION_NORMAL, OPERATION_MAINTENANCE, OPERATION_LEARNING, OPERATION_TESTING

5 export const operationModeG2R: {[key in gRPCOperationMode]: OperationMode|undefined} = {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Code generated by `@grpc/proto`:

```
export const OperationMode = {
  OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED: 0,
  OPERATION_NORMAL: 1,
  OPERATION_MAINTENANCE: 2,
  OPERATION_LEARNING: 3,
  OPERATION_TESTING: 4,
} as const;
```

Code defined in `rest-api.ts`

```
export enum OperationMode {
    NORMAL = 'NORMAL',
    MAINTENANCE = 'MAINTENANCE',
    LEARNING = 'LEARNING',
    TESTING = 'TESTING',
  }
```

```
import { OperationMode as gRPCOperationMode } from "../proto/generated/companyname/control/OperationMode";
import { OperationMode } from "./rest-api";

export const operationModeG2R: {[key in gRPCOperationMode]: OperationMode|undefined} = {
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_LEARNING]:OperationMode.LEARNING,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_MAINTENANCE]:OperationMode.MAINTENANCE,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_NORMAL]:OperationMode.NORMAL,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_TESTING]:OperationMode.TESTING,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED]:undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gRPCOperationMode` is a runtime value and can not be used inside of a mapped type because mapped types can only work with *types*.

You want to get the type of `gRPCOperationMode` using `typeof` and map over its keys with `keyof`. But the keys of `gRPCOperationMode` are string types. Since you want to get the number literal type of each key's value, you need to use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to map each key `K` into its corresponding type `gRPCOperationMode[K]`.

```
export const operationModeG2R: { 
  [K in keyof typeof gRPCOperationMode as typeof gRPCOperationMode[K]]: 
    OperationMode | undefined
} = {
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_LEARNING]:OperationMode.LEARNING,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_MAINTENANCE]:OperationMode.MAINTENANCE,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_NORMAL]:OperationMode.NORMAL,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_TESTING]:OperationMode.TESTING,
    [gRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED]:undefined
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wOYCUAKBhAeTGCgEMYBLFAWQgBNg4BeOAbwCg44CcBRLAIIAVAJIEAcgH0AquIDKfPCIBiI3gBEAXHAAMAGk7c+g0RMniCWagIAy2gIwGuPfsLFTrI8UN7iB4vF5tACYnI1dTKRteASxxLwBxbQBmMJcTd0kfOVFxJLgAFgMAXzhSVEQUdABudnZQSFg4YGQAVwBbbmIyShp6Rg4uLgsrW2Y4AHIR6xsJsK5Pb19-QPGJxZ8-AN45wy5o2Pi8tYO4xN2huGzchLXr85K6huh4JDR4CG7yKmRaBgTglhtKw4IYANoAaTgFGQcAA1sAAJ4QABmcBgiOIqLg2HwRBI3z6DDKFQxWLRuMIX16v36kIAuvTtHsugSaX9GAAfOCtZAMFEw4B0dilFiDIZgyn4no-DkAOnSbjMpyOCSZ0sJtIYcpViXmcEluCpbNl-QVxiVHgEXk2K146uppu1G2W231hrxjqJwHNEUy01sDpN3rlAZs7qlXq1PsVkSyvByiSDMpD9zyEaNGvZZtjmVkCl4SlUGiZvP5guFxSAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'm impressed/surprised that we need this amount of typing for such a trivial mapping, but that's probably just because the proto to typescript generator makes `const`s instead of `enum`s. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @tobias-s is the correct answer to my particular question.

However, after taking a look in the generated file, I can see that there's already a shorthand type `OperationMode__Output` for this case, which I want to share to anyone who come here by searching for the specific gRPC related issue:

```
// Original file: proto/autofuel.proto

export const OperationMode = {
  OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED: 0,
  OPERATION_NORMAL: 1,
  OPERATION_MAINTENANCE: 2,
  OPERATION_LEARNING: 3,
  OPERATION_TESTING: 4,
} as const;

export type OperationMode =
  | 'OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED'
  | 0
  | 'OPERATION_NORMAL'
  | 1
  | 'OPERATION_MAINTENANCE'
  | 2
  | 'OPERATION_LEARNING'
  | 3
  | 'OPERATION_TESTING'
  | 4

export type OperationMode__Output = typeof OperationMode[keyof typeof OperationMode]
```

Which means I can do it like this:

```
import { OperationMode as GRPCOperationMode, OperationMode__Output } from "../proto/generated/companyname/control/OperationMode";
import { OperationMode } from "./rest-api";

export const operationModeG2R: { 
  [K in OperationMode__Output]: 
    OperationMode | undefined
} = {
  [GRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_LEARNING]:OperationMode.LEARNING,
  [GRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_MAINTENANCE]:OperationMode.MAINTENANCE,
  [GRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_NORMAL]:OperationMode.NORMAL,
  [GRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_TESTING]:OperationMode.TESTING,
  [GRPCOperationMode.OPERATION_UNSPECIFIED]:undefined
}
```